# MVVM architecture in android Using Volley

Tags: java, android, mvvm, android-volley, android-viewmodel

I'm studying the MVVM to see if it can help me for my upcoming projects. What I understand so far, is that I need to use a [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModel.html) for holding my UI datas. I also need to use a Repository class to perform all my Requests to WebServices, and I'm using the Volley Library.

So here's what I did :

The [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModel.html)

```
public class MyViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private MyRepository repository;
    private MutableLiveData<MyPojo> pojo;

    public MyViewModel(MyRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
        this.pojo = new MutableLiveData<>();
    }

    public LiveData<MyPojo> updatePojo(){
        pojo.postValue(repository.getPojo());
        return pojo;
    }
}
```

The Repository class

```
public class MyRepository {

private Application application;
private LiveData<MyPojo> pojo;

public MyRepository(Application application) {
    this.application = application;
}

public MyPojo getPojo(){
    if(pojo == null){
        ApiRequest apiRequest = new ApiRequest(ApiSingleton.getInstance(application).getRequestQueue(), application);
        apiRequest.apiGetRequest(ApiRequest.MY_ENDPOINT, null, new ApiRequest.apiCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Context context, JSONObject jsonObject) {
                pojo = ApiResponseParser.parse(jsonObject, MyPojo.class);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Context context, String message) {

            }
        });
    }
    return pojo;
}
```

}

It's specified [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) that a [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModel.html) must never reference a view, Lifecycle, or any class that may hold a reference to the activity context. As you can see, I must use a context in order to perform a Volley request in my Repository class, and my ViewModel has a reference on this class.

Am I missing something in my design? Is Volley not compatible here?

Comment: Hi. Are you achieved the integration of Volley into MVVM pattern. I'm trying that without success. Have you any repository at Github or another with code example?

Comment: I want to learn mvvm can you please share your source code...it will be helpfull

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of passing the `Application` to your MyRepository's `constructor` and creating `ApiRequest`, you can pass the `ApiRequest` to MyRepository's `constructor`.

```
public MyRepository(ApiRequest apiRequest) {
    this.apiRequest = apiRequest;
}
```

Now the `MyRepository` has no reference to `Context`.

And, regarding `ViewModel` having direct reference to `MyRepository`, you can do [dependency inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle):

Create an `interface`, for instance, `MyDataStore` with the method `getPojo()`. `MyRepository` will implement this `interface`. While creating `MyViewModel`, you will pass the `MyRepository` to it, but `MyViewModel` will only have reference to `MyDataStore`.

```
interface MyDataStore {
   ... getPojo()
}

public class MyRepository implements MyDataStore {
   ...
}

public MyViewModel(MyDataStore dataStore) {
        this.dataStore = dataStore;
        this.pojo = new MutableLiveData<>();
}
```

Comment: Hi Bob, thanks for your answer. The problem here, is that ApiRequest needs to hold a reference on the context in order to performs HTTP requests, so even with this solution, the ViewHolder will still hold a reference to a context.
But you're right for the use of an interface, it's far better this way

Comment: Can't upvote with my current reputation, but your solution doesn't solve the problem as ApiRequest is holding a reference on the context

Comment: And that's bad because?

Comment: As mentionned here https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel the ViewModel class must never reference a class that may hold a reference to the activity context, and ApiRequest is that class .

What I understood here, is that the ViewModel will outlive the Fragment/Activity lifecycle and this could create memory leaks. Using an interface was a great idea, for the general design, but at runtime you will still end with a reference on the application's context, which is my main problem here
I'm starting to think Volley is just not compatible in this case

Comment: From the code you have posted above, I see ApiRequest has only Application context, not Activity context. So, ViewModel doesn't leak Activity in this case. If you have an Activity context in ApiRequest, then that's the problem. Since, it is independent of the Activity, and the ApiRequest doesn't depend on the Activity, it should use the Application context.

Comment: Well, you are right. The LifeCycle provides the AndroidViewModel class, and it looks it's pretty close to your solution! Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Hi, do you know any tutorial explaining how to integrate Volley into MVVM pattern?

Comment: @Bob can you please share the source code for making volley request in MVVM pattern

Answer (score 3):

The LifeCycle library provides the [AndroidViewModel](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/AndroidViewModel.html) component, which is just an Application's context aware [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModel.html), pretty close to Bob's answer, and did the job here without memory leaks hazards.