# How to integrate Volley into the MVVM pattern to periodically synchronize my remote database with my local database

Tags: android, android-volley, android-mvvm

I am trying to correctly implement the MVVM pattern in my application.

What I want to do is a regular synchronization of a local database on the device with a remote database.

The tools to achieve this would be the following:

- Use `PeriodicWorkRequest` for a periodic sync every X time
- Use `RequestFuture` from `Volley` to get the remote data.

I have no experience using the MVVM pattern and even though I have read various tutorials I cannot assemble my code.

What I want to achieve is something exactly similar to what is explained in this [repository](https://github.com/Ikhiloya/WorkManagerPeriodicRequest/tree/3b0ae3e0a9bbacbcfdf2486368492df0b64b1f0c/app/src/main/java/com/ikhiloyagersynhai/):  But in that code `Retrofit` is used, and I mostly get lost in the `service` part and **how to launch / embed / bind Volley's answer in an MVVM pattern**.

I have searched for tutorials on the subject and have not found any. I have a lot of code written, but I can't get it to work. As I mentioned before, I don't know exactly how to link the elements in the correct way and that is my main question: how to integrate Volley into the MVVM pattern to periodically synchronize my remote database with my local database?

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59331734/mvvm-architecture-in-android-using-volley